# Editable UITableView design

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a question regarding a design convention.. See I have this tableview filled with editable information. Editable as in changing the text in the right detail of the cell, not as in deleting or moving a cell. I wonder how to design/model this, the only Apple product that I know has this feature is the contacts app. The solution there is to make lots and lots of groups, but this does not fit my problem at all, partly since I already have groups. The simplest way would just be to have the right detail be a text field and enable it in edit mode, but that would of course be a stupid solution since no visual feedback is given..

Any ideas on how to design/model this, or how Apple would like to have it?

EDIT:

To be more clear in what I mean, this is a screenshot explaining what I have said. Once again, my problem is how to show the table cells when they are in edit mode. All values are changeable, and none of them have any kind of presets to choose from, they are all based on text written by the user. This part of the app is basically a CRM system, where you can edit all the information about yourself.

[image: Example]

Comment: "right detail" as in the text that shows up in the label on the right side of the cell, correct?

Comment: Design 'this,' design that...  What is 'this'?  What is the right detail?  Nobody knows but you that you are exactly talking about.  You'd better make it clear before people start down-voting you.

Comment: @GeneralMike That is correct.

Comment: @TBlue Sorry about that, added screenshot and some more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is pretty standard for `Dynamic Prototype` cells (as opposed to the `Static Cells` you probably used to make that screenshot).  You're best bet is probably going to be to just [watch a couple of these tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=uitableview+tutorial&oq=uitableview&gs_l=youtube.1.2.35i39l2j0l8.4800.6146.0.9464.11.11.0.0.0.0.117.771.9j2.11.0...0.0...1ac.1.11.youtube.Rrsy9N3GrC0).

To give a quick summary, you're going to put all the strings you want to show in the `Value` part of your screenshot into an `NSArray`.  There are `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods that will automatically handle putting the ith item in the array into the ith cell (so the 3 item in the array will go into the 3rd cell, etc.).  To allow the user to edit things, you're going to want to make a whole new second screen (this is where you're `UITextfields` will be).  When the user goes back from the second screen to your table screen, you replace items in the array with whatever the user entered in the `UITextfield`, then tell the `UITableViewDelegate` methods to reload the table with the new `Value`s.

Most of the tutorials I linked to probably aren't going to have anything about having multiple Groups, so I'll add a bit on that here (what follows will probably only make sense if you watch the tutorials first, so I'd suggest following along with the tutorials, then coming back here afterward and making the changes I'm about to suggest).  The `NSIndexPath` that is sent to the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method contains information on the cell `row` and `section`.  Each "Group" is it's own `section` (I'm really not sure why Apple decided to use two different names for the same thing, but so it goes).  The easiest way to do this is to have different arrays for each section (so you'll have lines for `NSMutableArray *firstSectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`, `NSMutableArray *secondSectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`, and so on).  Then, at the very top of your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you put some `if` statements in to see what `section` of the table you are "building", and use values from the correct array accordingly.  Something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
         // bunch of stuff from the tutorials here to create "cell"

         [cell.detailTextLabel.text = firstSectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

         // bunch more stuff
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
         // bunch of stuff from the tutorials here to create "cell"

         [cell.detailTextLabel.text = secondSectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

         // bunch more stuff
    }
    // else if (keep going for however many sections you have)

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a very elaborate answer!